# How to get string between two characters in bash

Tags: bash

How to get string between two characters like:

```
https://hello.world.example.com
```

to get `hello` between `//` and `.`   I try the following:

```
echo 'https://hello.world.example.com' | awk -F[/.] '{print $2}'
```

looks like it can be parsed

how to parse the string between `//` and `.`?

thanks!

Comment: I try that, but how to get only hello part?

Comment: You are looking for field number three and not two.

Answer (score 2):

Bash itself has string manipulation procedures.

Try:

```
s='https://hello.world.example.com'


s1="${s#*//}"   # Deletes shortest match of *// from front of $s
s2="${s1%%.*}"  # Delete longest match of .* (ie, from first .) in s1

echo "$s2"
# hello
```

In the first case, `#*//` is the shortest match from the front of the string up to and including `//`.

In the second case, `%%.*` matches the longest sub string from the literal '.' to the end of the string represented by `*`

You can read more [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

---

Or use `sed`:

```
echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^[^/]*\/\/([^.]*)\..*/\1/'
                    ^                              Substitute
                      ^                            Start of string
                         ^                         Not a /
                            ^                      Two literal //
                                ^                  Capture that
                                        ^          Literal .
                                          ^        The rest of the string
                                            ^      The replacement 
                                                   is the captured word
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain how it works.

Comment: Explanation added...